# Fundamentals of Magento 2 Development (On-Demand): Unit One Course Missing File in Reinforcement Exercise (1.2.1)

Tags: magento2

In the first Reinforcement Exercise (1.2.1) of  Fundamentals of Magento 2 Development v2.0 - Unit One (FREE), it states to go to lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php file to throw an exception. This path does not exist from the root of the site.

The only directories in the lib/internal/Magento folder are
Cm            Credis            LinLibertineFont

I’m really interested in purchasing the full course, but the training material isn’t matching the 2.0.5 version of the site. Can you please assist? Maybe this directory is in a different path?

Note: I have sent emails to training@magento.com (twice over the past 2 weeks) and posted on their forums to no avail. I hope the community here will be able to respond.

Thank you

Comment: but the file is there: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php

Comment: I may be stupid but I'm struggling to find the Reinforcement Exercises, I can only find the solutions. I wrote to support but still no answer. Can anyone please indicate where I can find it? tnx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Magento framework sources are located at `lib/internal/Magento/` on the github repository, but the build process they use for releases moves every Magento module into the vendor folder as a composer package: `vendor/magento/`

That being the case, look for your missing file at `vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php`.

Likewise, any references to code in `app/code/Magento/` can be found in the same place, named `vendor/magento/module-{module_key}/`. Once you find the right folder, all folder paths and file names within that namespace should match exactly.

This should really be explained in the course. It was probably an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

In packages you download from magento page the data is located under `magento_root/vendor/magento/`

This should point you to the correct path. Good luck!